# How to make Thunderbird split EVEN and ODD emails in two different folders?

Tags: email, thunderbird

Two persons use same e-mail for orders and they get picky about the prices of the orders(they look for bigger ones so they receive more $$ as bonus) and they leave the small orders behind.

I want to be able to split incoming e-mail in two folders - one odd and another even folder . Some sort of 'random' order assignment so they dont leave small orders behind.

I looked everywhere but I couldnt find anything related to this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a training problem with your personnel.

Or if these emails already contain a unique number, perhaps one person gets all the odd numbers and the other person gets evens.

Comment: Any way to number each email in Thunderbird?

Comment: Don't they already come in with an order number associated with it?   If they don't then use some other field which an be a proxy for flipping a coin - for example person A gets all the orders whose incoming time ends in an odd digit, and person B gets orders for the others, which end in an even digit. For example 1:01 PM would be chosen by person A.